# Newbie python error in regards to import

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm a python newbie and starting out with using the Bottle web framework on Google App Engine.  I've been messing with the super small, super easy Hello World sample and have already ran into problems.  Heh.  I finally got the code to work with this...

```
import bottle
from bottle import route
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util 

@route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello World!"

util.run_wsgi_app(bottle.default_app())
```

My question is, I thought I could just go 'import bottle' without the second line.  But if I take the second line out, I get a NameError.  Or if I do 'from bottle import *', I still get the error.  bottle is just a single file called 'bottle.py' in my site's root directory. So neither of these work....

```
import bottle
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util 

@route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello World!"

util.run_wsgi_app(bottle.default_app())
```

Or

```
from bottle import *
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util 

@route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello World!"

util.run_wsgi_app(bottle.default_app())
```

The error message I get is...

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 3180, in _HandleRequest
>       self._Dispatch(dispatcher, self.rfile, outfile, env_dict)   File
>   "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 3123, in _Dispatch
>       base_env_dict=env_dict)   File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 515, in Dispatch
>       base_env_dict=base_env_dict)   File
>   "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 2382, in Dispatch
>       self._module_dict)   File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 2292, in ExecuteCGI
>       reset_modules = exec_script(handler_path, cgi_path,
>   hook)   File
>   "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 2188, in ExecuteOrImportScript
>       exec module_code in script_module.**dict**   File
>   "/Users/tyler/Dropbox/sites/dietgrid/code2.py",
>   line 4, in 
>       @route('/') NameError: name 'route' is not defined

So am I wrong in thinking it should be able to work the other ways or no?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your code you have two different ways of calling methods from bottle package.

```
route('/hello')
```

and

```
bottle.default_app()
```

First call requires `from bottle import route` or `from bottle import *` and second one requires `import bottle`.

`from foo import bar` is letting you to use method or parameter `bar` in your code without specifying the package on each call.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding why

```
from bottle import *
```

does not do the trick: when you import like that, only names that are specified in bottle's _____all_____ list are imported. So, if route is not there, you have to specify the import explicitly:

```
from bottle import route
```

Answer (score 3):

`route` is part of the `bottle` module.

The following should fix the problem

```
import bottle
...

@bottle.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either just import bottle into you namespace, so every time you wish to use something from there you have `bottle.` as a prefix.

```
import bottle
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util 

@bottle.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello World!"

util.run_wsgi_app(bottle.default_app())
```

The other way is to import the parts of bottle you are going to use into your namespace.

```
from bottle import route, default_app
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util 

@route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello World!"

util.run_wsgi_app(default_app())
```

Answer (score 0):

I too learned to use Bottle with GAE, because of its very small size. What you can do is keep bottle directly with your main files, that will allow you to use 'import bottle', or put in a folder (to separate it from other files, give a neat structure), and add an empty `__init__.py` file to that folder. Then you can import it as `import bottle from <foldername>` and so on.
I wrote a small tutorial on [how to use Bottle with GAE](http://blog.rutwick.com/use-bottle-python-framework-with-google-app-engine).