# How I can run /myapp/my_app.py by default when accessing `localhost` using Bottle?

Tags: python-2.7, mod-wsgi, bottle

**Desired Behaviour**

I want to serve content created by the file at:

```
/myapp/my_app.py
```

when accessing `localhost`.

**Question**

I know that if I add the following to `test.py` and run the file directly, the results will be accessible at `localhost:8080`:

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

But how do I trigger this file to run by default when accessing `localhost`?

**Environment**

- Linux Mint 17
- MongoDB
- RockMongo (Apache2, PHP, MongoDB Driver)

**What I've Tried**

I installed `mod_wsgi` and created `/var/www/html/myapp/app.wsgi` with this content:

```
import bottle
import os

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))

@route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

application = bottle.default_app()
```

And then restarted Apache.

But going to `localhost` just shows a file directory.

I then created `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mygreatapp.conf` with this content:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName google.com

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/myapp/app.wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/html/myapp>
    WSGIProcessGroup yourapp
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But I still just see a file directory.

**Official Instructions**

http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/deployment.html#apache-mod-wsgi

**Further Information**

**Troubleshooting**

*See if mod_wsgi is loaded*

```
apache2ctl -M
...
wsgi_module (shared)
```

**Definitions**

For my own reference, I'm trying to fully comprehend several elements that I think are involved in the process, feel free to correct if my understandings are wrong:

**WSGI** - A convention for how applications should communicate with servers.

> It does not exist anywhere else other than as words in the [PEP 3333](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/) - [Source](http://webpython.codepoint.net/wsgi_tutorial)

**mod_wsgi** - An Apache module that allows Python files to communicate with Apache.

**Web Framework** - See a list of them here:  https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks

**Web Server** - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server

**Apache Server** - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server

Comment: What happens when you hit `http://localhost/`?

Comment: A file directory is shown ie `Index of /`.

Comment: I think I just need to definitively know - what should be in `/myapp/app.wsgi` (this will run Bottle) and `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/appy.conf` (this will tell Apache where to look for the first file).

Answer (score 0):

I finally have "Hello World!" displaying in the browser at `localhost`.

I will paste the various required configs and files below.

I'm a newb so I don't know if this is definitive or best practise.

**/var/www/html/myapp/app.wsgi**

```
# view the effect of import method:  
http://stackoverflow.com/a/2452639/1063287

import bottle 
import os

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# note i am using bottle.route and not just route
@bottle.route('/') 
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

application = bottle.default_app()
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf** (note: this is the default `.conf` file)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/myapp/app.wsgi # just added this
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Viewing the Apache error log is what eventually led me to try a few different things:

```
sudo tail -100 /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Where I saw things like:

```
Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/myapp/app.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/html/myapp/app.wsgi", line 8, in <module>
@route('/')
NameError: name 'route' is not defined
```

This was only after I had made the step of not using a new `.conf` file and just modifying the default one.

So for some reason it didn't like any new `.conf` files.